# Error saving DbContext Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core and my context is configured with SQL Server. When I to call `context.SaveChangesAsync` I get the following error message:

> Failed executing DbCommand (3,643ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000), @p1='?' (DbType = Int32), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (Size = 4000), @p4='?' (DbType = DateTime2), ...

And the inner exception is:

> Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with text

Does anyone know what this means?

For context, this is my `DbContext`:

```
public class ComparisonInfoContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ComparisonInfo> Comparisons { get; set; } = null!;

    public ComparisonInfoContext(DbContextOptions<ComparisonInfoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

And this is `ComparisonInfo` (the entity it the `DbSet`).

```
public class ComparisonInfo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public DateTime InitiatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string Version1 { get; set; }
    public string Version2 { get; set; }
    public string ControlDb1 { get; set; }
    public string ControlDb2 { get; set; }
    public string Org { get; set; }
    public JobStatus VersionStatus1 { get; set; }
    public JobStatus VersionStatus2 { get; set; }
    public ComparisonResult ComparisonResult { get; set; }
    public List<DiscrepancyInfo> DiscrepancyInfos { get; set; } = new List<DiscrepancyInfo>();
    public bool HasBeenPassedToComparePay { get; set; } = false;
}
```

And lastly here is `DiscrepancyInfo` (`ComparisonInfo` stores a list of this):

```
public class DiscrepancyInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    //this is an enum
    public DiscrepancyPattern DiscrepancyPattern { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment I am trying to save, the DbSet contains only a single instance of `ComparisonInfo` and the instance's list of `DiscrepancyInfo`'s is empty.

Comment: You need to **AT LEAST** show us **(1)** what your entity involved looks like, **(2)** how it is defined in the `DbContext`, and **(3)** what you're doing in your code that leads up to this error .....

Comment: I still don't see point **(3)** - the code that you run that then throws that error - what **exactly** are you doing there??

Comment: @marc_s I mentioned that it crashes when I call `context.SaveChangesAsync` and that the DbSet contains only a single instance at that point. I don't see what else I could mention.

Comment: What's the schema of the ComparisonInfo table in the database? There seems to be a type mapping issue: one of your `DateTime` properties is probably backed by a `char`/`varchar`/`nchar`/`nvarchar`/`text`/`ntext` column in the table. The last two types, `text`/`ntext`, have been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 so you should definitely avoid those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was happening because I was previously using SqlLite instead of SqlServer. All the migrations were made for SqlLite and deleting them fixed the issue.

Comment: The real issue was that SQLite has no Date types (or types in general) so string is used instead. You may have similar problems with other types, eg using `float` instead of `numeric` with a specific scale and precision